# permuting a path while keeping end vertices constant?

Tags: igraph

I have animal movement paths from GPS collars (the animal's location was recorded every 2h). To study how the actual path compares to random paths I need to generate alternate paths by randomly distributing the original route segments between the actual beginning and end locations (first and last vertices). I thought a good way to go would be to use the permute.vertices function in igraph. However, I cannot figure out how to keep the first and last vertices constant.

Here is a sample data set:

I'm starting out with a matrix of from-coordinates and to-coordinates that define the steps:

```
library(igraph)
path <- matrix (c(-111.52, -111.49, -111.48, -111.47, -111.46, 
    35.34, 35.35, 35.33, 35.32, 35.31,
    -111.49, -111.48, -111.47, -111.46, -111.5,
    35.35, 35.33, 35.32, 35.31, 35.4),
    nrow=5, ncol=4)

path<-as.data.frame(path)
names(path)<-c("From.x","From.y","To.x","To.y")
From <- 0:(nrow(path)-1)
To <- 1:nrow(path)
path <- cbind(From, To, path)
```

Turning the data.frame into a graph:

```
path <- graph.data.frame(path,directed=FALSE)
V(path)
```

Randomly permuting the vertices:

```
path2 <- permute.vertices(path, permutation=sample(vcount(path)))
V(path2)
```

How could I write the code to keep the first and last vertices always "0" and "5"? (or depending on the path, of course, a different number than "5")

I also then need to extract the coordinates from the permuted path and get them into a matrix. I tried it with the tkplot.getcoords command, but am not sure how to transform them back (I suppose tkplot transforms them somehow).

```
tkplot(path2)
kplot.getcoords(1, norm = TRUE)
```

I'm using RStudio on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Then just permute the rest of the vertices, and keep `0` and `5`:

```
perm <- c(1, sample(2:(vcount(path)-1)), 5)
perm
# [1] 1 4 5 3 2 5
path2 <- permute.vertices(path, permutation=perm)
V(path2)
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] "0" "4" "3" "1" "5" "0"
```

For your other question, please explain better what you want, because I am not sure what kind of matrix you want to create.